# Incremental Build: Eclipse CDT does not notice that source has changed

Tags: c++, build, makefile, eclipse-cdt

When clicking the "Build" symbol in Eclipse CDT, it is supposed to build only the source files which have changed. A very annoying behavior of Eclipse CDT is that it very often ignores that "minor" changes have been made, but it is not clear what minor means.

The output then is

```
13:21:06 **** Incremental Build of configuration <config> for project <proj> ****
make all 
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

The only way for me to test the changes I just made is then to clean and completely rebuild the entire project, which wastes a lot of time.

What could be the problem here and how can I fix incremental building?

EDIT: Could it be that not minor, but very recent changes are ignored because of some clock synchronization issue?

Comment: Your description doesn't include more than one PC. What clocks should be out of sync? Have you all in one project or do you use libraries? Is the change of "source" file really in a file that is "in the project" not "used by the project"? When you check manually the time stamp of the changed source file and the resulting object file, is the object file really older than the source?

Comment: I can't imagine which clocks could be out of sync. Maybe I don't leave Eclipse enough time to scan the source before clicking the build button? I use libraries, but the changes I make are all to files within the project.

Comment: Might it happen that you just altered header files and not the corresponding cpp-files? That is one of the usual drawbacks of Makefiles, which eclipse uses internally.

Comment: @Thilo Most of my edits are in .cpp files, but this might be a reason why it happens sometimes. I'll pay attention to that.

Comment: @Thilo Yes, it seems that edits to .h files are ignored. I didn't imagine that make is broken to such an extent.

Comment: @cls This is rather a conceptual problem than a broken make - to know which compilation units have to be recompiled, make needs to know which cpp includes which header. This can not be done by just looking at timestamps, which is mostly everything make does.

Comment: I'm sure there are compelling technical reasons for that, but from a user perspective, it is simply annoying and counterproductive. I have to remember whether I just edited only .h or also .cpp and depending on that, do an incremental build or a complete rebuild.

Comment: @Thilo What about the ".d" files which Eclipse accesses? Shouldn't they document the dependencies so that only files depending on the new headers will be built?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you made your changes only in header file, you should clean your project so that the changes are included in new compilation. Changes in macro definitions and static variables also require a clean of the project in Eclipse CDT.

Comment: And why the developer should take care of it ? Why Eclipse cannot do it automatically (to do the clean if the header changed) ?  I think the proposed above is not a solution.